# "possesses some amount of Japanese"

Tags: phrases, style

Can I use the verb "possess" in describing a person's level of proficiency in some language?

> Just like his brother Henry, he **possesses some amount of Japanese** that
>   enables him to handle simple conversations and express himself more or
>   less correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People would understand what you meant but the expression would not be idiomatic.

More natural ways of saying this include:

> has some knowledge of..
>   has some fluency in...
>   can communicate/converse in...
>   can make himself understood in...

and, as you say,

> can express himself in

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat dated idiom is to "[have](https://books.google.com/books?id=REAzgei2YQAC&pg=PA295&dq=%22has%20no%20english%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNhPX4h7bfAhUvxVkKHd6dDD8Q6AEIOjAD#v=onepage&q=%22has%20no%20english%22&f=false)" a language.

> We simply cannot hire her. She has no English at all.